# Android 5 date and time pickers are not accessible

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, accessibility

Basically I've just got a new Android 5 phone and I've encountered a severe problem. I use the TalkBack screenreader service, and I cannot find any way to select a time in the new time picker in Android 5. Furthermore, the date picker is a pain to use (although at least it is usable).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out you have to navigate to the circular thing and then make the scroll gesture which is right-then-left to increment the number and left-then-right to decrement it.